# Decapsulate and encapsulate GENEVE packet

Tags: linux, networking

I would like to get some help on my project below please. I have the following topology.

```
<EC2 instance 1> --> <AWS GWLB> --> <EC2 instance 2>
```

The EC2 instances are just Ubuntu 20.04 AMIs.
AWS GWLB stands for AWS Gateway Load Balancer.
`EC2 instance 1` is emitting the "client" trafic, which is routed through the `AWS GWLB`, which is then sending it through `EC2 instance 2`.

The `EC2 instance 1` trafic is automatically forwarded through `AWS GWLB` with the routing table I created. `EC2 instance 2` acts as a backend server behind `AWS GWLB`.

I want to be able to forward different protocols, like UDP, ICMP, TCP, etc and that's why I choosed to use the GENEVE protocol, which is supported by `AWS GWLB`. This last encapsulates the `EC2 instance 1` packet by adding a new GENEVE header.

With this actual infrastructure, if I run a `ping` on `EC2 instance 1` (client) and a `tcpdump` on `EC2 instance 2` (backend), I can see the `ICMP request` encapsulated with a GENEVE header coming to `EC2 instance 2`.

What I want to do next is to

- "decapsulate" this `ICMP request` packet by removing the GENEVE header;
- Forwarding it to its destination (I assume that if I set up masquerading on `EC2 instance 2` and enable IPv4 forwarding, it's gonna be OK);
- Reencapsulate the `ICMP reply` and send it back to `EC2 instance 1` through `AWS GWLB`.

There are not a lot of documentation about what I plan to do. The only interesting things I found are :

- Linux `tc` : https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tc.8.html;
- This blog post that was interesting but didn't worked : https://darjchen.medium.com/setting-up-geneve-tunnel-with-linux-tc-571f891618a9.

Is `tc` the best solution about what I plan to do ? If yes, how can I use it ?

Thanks for your future help ! I hope you have a wonderful day !

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? if so, can you please share it?

Comment: No. I gave up. I built a loadbalancer myself with ECMP on a Linux machine. I use a specific routing table and automatically update the default route for this table when I make changes to the "backends".

Comment: May be this helps? https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-gateway-load-balancer-tunnel-handler